# Pandas: Select first occurrence when defining a value_count() int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, count

I would like to know how can one select the first observation in a dataframe where the value_count() equals a certain value.

I attempted the following:

```
trip_id_value_count = trip_df["trip_id"].value_counts()

trip1 = trip_df[(trip_id_value_count == 378)]
```

However, I got the error:

**IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).**

As the value count can be repeated, I'd like to keep the first occurrence of it. My end goal is to extract different trips that differ in the amount of observations. For instance, this trip1 in particular would have 378 observations. Others might have 121, 50, and so on...

The output I am expecting is a dataframe containing all the rows of that trip_id that has the selected value count. For example, if the trip_id 626xy83m has a value count of 378 and it is the first trip_id showing in the dataframe with this value count, I would like to extract it as a dataframe and store it in trip1.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a sample dataframe with your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

trip_df = pd.DataFrame()
trip_df["trip_id"] = np.random.randint(1,10, 10_000)
```

Then I generate a value_counts column in the dataframe

```
trip_df["value_counts"] = trip_df["trip_id"].map(trip_df["trip_id"].value_counts())
```

in this case I get:

```
      trip_id  value_counts
0           4          1155
1           3          1135
2           5          1119
3           8          1111
4           9          1124
...       ...           ...
9995        7          1051
9996        4          1155
9997        3          1135
9998        1          1073
9999        2          1080

[10000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Then you can filter the dataframe:

```
trip_df[trip_df["value_counts"] == 1155].head(1)
```

Output:

```
   trip_id  value_counts
0        4          1155
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
trip_id_378 = trip_id_value_count[trip_id_value_count == 378].index[0]

trip1 = df_trip.loc[df_trip['trip_id'] == trip_id_378]
```